# Land Use / Land Cover Change using Landsat 8 L2SP - Preprocessing

Tags: arcgis-pro, landsat

For Landsat 8 Collection 2 Level 2 Science Products, do we need to perform any type of correction before doing Land Use Land Cover analysis? For instance, do we need to remove each pixel outside of the valid range (see image bellow)? My LULC analysis is using bands 1-7 to classify the raster.

**Image 1: Characteristics of L2SP bands - Image was captured from Landsat 8-9 Collection 2 (C2) Level 2 Science Product (L2SP) Guide)**

[image]

Comment: Convert DN to reflectance (with scale and offset). Pixels with values out of valid range have reflectance less than 0 or over 1

Comment: But do we need to do this for all the bands (1-7)? @aldo_tapia

Comment: if you want to compute a spectral index, yes. If you will use the bands without any transformation, isn't needed

Comment: No, I just need to compute land use / land cover, and nothing else. No computation for indices  needed. So I can use the bands right away ? @aldo_tapia.

Comment: My question is, do I need surface reflectance for LULC ?@aldo_tapia

Comment: For LULC, many use spectral indices as input in the classification model. In that case, it's necessary to apply the transformation. If you are gonna use only the bands, isn't needed. If you will use a machine learning algorithm, the recommendation is scale data with mean = 0 or to 0-1 range